# CGPoint, NSTimeInterval not showing value on debugger view

Tags: swift, debugging, swift2

I cannot see the values of local variables of type CGPoint or NSTimeInterval in the debugger's variables window. To reproduce it all I do is the following:

```
let x = 5 * 4
let y = CGPoint(x: 5, y: 4)
<Breakpoint here>
```

When cursor stops at the given breakpoint the debugger variables window show the value of x to be equal to 20 and it does not show a value for y, and when I hover on y it shows a tool tip text saying "y".

I wonder what's causing this problem?

Thanks!

I am using Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.1

Doing "po y" will give me the following error: error: :1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'y'

Comment: I think it's a bug.  Probably related to CoreGraphics bridging to Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. I have filed it to Apple under bug #23266337, they have marked it as duplicate for bug #23088739

Answer (score 1):

Try simply "print y" because y is a struct not an object.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in xcode because a class with instance variables of CGPoint type show their value, while CGPoint local variables of a method in the same class do not show their value.  Local variables that are objects or primitive types also show their value, but not structs like CGPoint CGRect.